# QT-QML: How to create image (line) and work on it

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

I need to create and move an image on Qt but i cannot understand how to do that.
The image is just a line like the following:[image]

The result that I'd like to obtain is to have a line which I can shift right or left (it should continue even outside the canvas for some cm) and color the line(or glowing it white with another background) when I call a function.

To do that im using a qml file in qt and I'm creating this line by using the Canvas object, but it is far away from the image showed before:

```
Canvas {
    id: mycanvas
    width: 1000; height: 600
    contextType: "2d"
    property var l_mez: 273
    property var pp: 245

    Path {          
        id: myPath
        startX: 100; startY: 300
        PathCurve { x: (100+(mycanvas.l_mez/2)); y: (300+mycanvas.pp/2) }
        PathCurve { x: 100+(mycanvas.l_mez*3/2)-40; y: 300-mycanvas.pp/2+15 }
        PathCurve { x: 100+(mycanvas.l_mez*3/2)+40; y: 300-mycanvas.pp/2+15 }

        PathCurve { x: 100+(mycanvas.l_mez*2); y: 300}

        PathCurve { x: 100+(mycanvas.l_mez*5/2); y: 300+mycanvas.pp/2 }
        PathCurve { x: 100+(mycanvas.l_mez*7/2); y: 300-mycanvas.pp/2 }
    }


    onPaint: {          
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "grey"; 
        ctx.path = myPath;
        ctx.lineWidth =9
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

The result is :
[image]

The question is, how can i properly draw the line on the first image?
I was thinking I could just create the image and import it but then I could not shift it and change the color of the line as I prefer.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PathCurve` is really overspecifying the curve in your example which is where the waviness is coming from. I would instead use alternating `PathLine` and `PathArc` to achieve that look.

Note, you could do this with an image also if you were willing to give up on changing the line color. You can load your sample image above twice and place them next to each other so that they seamless connect. You would place them both inside of one Item and turn on clipping.

Then you translate them both left or right to give the sense of movement. When you get to the far end of the images in either direction you just jump the translation back by the image width and keep going.

It will look seamless and smooth to the user. Especially if you use an XAnimator as those run in a separate thread.

Comment: Yeah, my play B was exactly the use of 2 images where the second one faded in during the translation to simulate the color changing. I will try PathLine and PathArc as you indicated, if it will take too long I will switch to planB (I weren't sure that could be a "good" practice). Thanks for your help